# PostgreSQL won't start because it "Cannot allocate memory"

Tags: linux, kernel, postgresql, linux-kernel

I'm running PostgreSQL 8.4.5 on Ubuntu 10.04. I run an EC2 instance with a few sites running on nginx. Most of these sites run on Django and connect to this Postgres instance.

For some reason, at 8:45pm tonight, Postgres went down. I logged into the machine, and I see this error message:

```
 * Starting PostgreSQL 8.4 database server
 * The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
2011-04-17 04:46:49 UTC FATAL:  could not create shared memory segment: Cannot allocate memory
2011-04-17 04:46:49 UTC DETAIL:  Failed system call was shmget(key=5432001, size=16211968, 03600).
2011-04-17 04:46:49 UTC HINT:  This error usually means that PostgreSQL's request for a shared memory segment exceeded available memory or swap space. To reduce the request size (currently 16211968 bytes), reduce PostgreSQL's shared_buffers parameter (currently 1792) and/or its max_connections parameter (currently 53).
        The PostgreSQL documentation contains more information about shared memory configuration.
   ...fail!
```

The first thing I did was change the Linux shared memory allocation.

```
sysctl -w kernel.shmmax=367108864>
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```

That didn't do it. So then I edited `/etc/postgresql/8.4/main/postgresql.conf` and lowered the `max_connections` value. That worked...for about 10 minutes.

Now I'm getting the same error, no matter how low `max_connections` is. I need to set it to at least 9 (since that's the number of Django projects that need access to this Postgres server).

Any thoughts on how I might go about fixing this?

Comment: restart the server, that should free any used shared memory, than start the postgres

Comment: @Troydm the server already went down, so ideally any shared memory should already have been freed. Per @janneb's suggestion I'm going to try to manually delete the SHM segments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the 'ipcs' command to list all the SHM segments. If a program crashes without deleting them, they may be lying around consuming memory; you can remove these manually with the 'ipcrm' command.

Answer (score 1):

Some googling indicates that you should reduce the postgres shared_buffers *and* max_connections numbers.  have you done anything with shared_buffers yet?

Have you reviewed the [postgresql shared memory documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/kernel-resources.html#SYSVIPC)?  Lots of details in there about how to tune the shared memory parameters on a linux machine.

Comment: Yep, I also reduced `shared_buffers` (although, I'm unsure how much to lower them to). I stopped when it seemed the lowering had gone too low--what's a good benchmark for when to start? I don't want to be running on 0 `shared_buffers` (may hurt performance?)

Answer (score 1):

Can you show more verbose cluster log ? Is postmaster crashing arbitrarily ? Which code it returns to OS ? How many PostgreSQL clusters you have, only 8.4/main ?

What about your kernel.shmall and kernel.shmmni ? Try to use ipcs -ml, ipcs -m and check your memory (free, top, System Monitor) usage . Try to calm down OOM killer:

```
vm.overcommit_memory = 2
vm.overcommit_ratio = 50
```

AFAIK `sysctl -w` does not change params permanently (only until next OS reboot) and you need to add `kernel.shmmax=367108864` to /etc/sysctl.conf.

If possible upgrade your PostgreSQL to 8.4.8 as suggested in [Versioning policy](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning):

> We always recommend that all users run
>   the latest available minor release for
>   whatever major version is in use.

I think this is probably OOM killer issue, because it kills postmaster with SIGKILL signal and **without** releasing shared memory. Look at [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/server-shutdown.html):

> Important: It is best not to use
>   SIGKILL to shut down the server. Doing
>   so will prevent the server from
>   releasing **shared memory** and
>   semaphores, which might then have to
>   be done manually before a new server
>   can be started. Furthermore, SIGKILL
>   kills the postgres process without
>   letting it relay the signal to its
>   subprocesses, so it will be necessary
>   to kill the individual subprocesses by
>   hand as well.

and [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/kernel-resources.html):

> n Linux 2.4 and later, the default
>   virtual memory behavior is not optimal
>   for PostgreSQL. Because of the way
>   that the kernel implements memory
>   overcommit, the kernel might terminate
>   the PostgreSQL server (the master
>   server process) if the memory demands
>   of another process cause the system to
>   run out of virtual memory.

BTW max_connections are "cheap". Rather reduce shared_buffers.

Comment: I only have one Postgres server running, it is not a cluster.

Comment: http://people.debian.org/~mpitt/architecture.html One server is a so called "database cluster" (or catalog cluster in SQL standard) created by initdb.

Comment: Interesting...well then, I suppose I am running a cluster. I haven't had any downtime with my above fix, and I am reluctant to change the configuration lest it go down again. I'm trying to see if I can replicate the issue on a non-production database.